# Spring boot + Oauth2 + Jwt

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

Am trying to create a Spring boot application, where admin need a different login with form login [Default spring form login], Customers need to login through Angular app. Customer have a provision to login locally and Social [Google]. Can any one suggest me a document.

I don't need a `sso` as am not gonna include third party login.

I gone through internet for 2 days, and i could't find a solution.

Comment: To understand your question, lets simplify a bit. Assume, you have one login url and login page for one set of users and another login url and different login page for other users. So when unauthenticated user tries to access a url that is protected, system needs to redirect to login page. Since it is unauthenticated user, system does not know whether to redirect to first login page or second login page. So if you can tell me how logically you plan to resolve this, then I may be able to point to some implemenation or document

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai, Thanks for the help, Actually I have a DB with different user roles [Admin, user]. Spring boot is serving as a backend in this application. Angular is used for the front end section. along with that admin panel is integrated in the using thymleaf.  So in my case, Users should able to login from angular app using username&password or social login[JWT and Oauth2]. For adminpanel, we need a separate form login[Basic spring login form]. Can you help me resolve this issue. Please suggest me a method to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: So for angular app, is the login screen is going to be like this https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f (Open it in Incognito widow)?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai yes, and if we goto `domain.com/admin/login` we get another basic form login. Which is a admin login page. And admin don't need the angular app. Only users allowed.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. If you managed to get this working, I can help you with panel

Answer (score 1):

**The following will allow you to use login via form login or Github Oauth2 login**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and().
            oauth2Login().
                loginPage("/login");;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecuringWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(SecuringWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`src/main/resources/templates/login.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login/authenticate}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
        <a href="/oauth2/authorization/github">Click here to login via Github</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

`src/main/resources/templates/hello.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>This is a secured page. Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`src/main/resources/templates/home.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" 
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome! This is not a secured page</h1>
        
        <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a secured page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

`pom.xml`

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

`application.yaml`

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            client-id: your-github-client-id
            client-secret: your-github-client-secret
```

Note:

You will have to generate the github client and secret as described in the following reference.

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#github-register-application

These are the filters that get chained by the above config, feel free to put a breakpoint in filters 5, 6, 7, 12 and 13 then

- try to access unsecured url `/home` and see what happens
- try to access secured url `/hello` and see what happens
- try to access `login` url and see what happens
- try to submit `login` from and see what happens
- click `login via Github` link and see what happens

[image]